# Are local variables of consecutive structs being held in consecutive memory locations?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

For example, consider the following code:

```
struct user
{
    char username[20];
};

struct admin
{
    char rootpass[20];
};
```

Can I overwrite rootpass by overflowing username?

Comment: How separate variables are related in memory is not specified by the language. A buffer overflow causes undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: You are showing the declaration which doesn't allocate any memory.  The memory will be defined when you define a variable of that struct type.  But, as was mentioned in the previous comment, you can't make any assumptions about the memory layout.

Comment: If this is for writing code, the answer is "don't ever let `username` overflow and you won't have to worry about it".  If it's for constructing an attack, the answer is "it depends on what the compiler decided to do in this particular case - you have to look at the generated code."  I certainly don't know any compiler that makes guarantees about how local variables will be laid out in the stack - in some cases they might be held in registers and never appear on the stack at all.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you can you shouldn't.

The answer to your question depends on architecture and compiler, but you shouldn't even be asking this question.

NEVER access array elements out of range (for an array defined as [N] only elements 0 ... N-1 are valid).

Comment: @P__J__ I completely agree. Even asking questions for which the answer seems obvious challenges others and yourself, which is a good thing.

But whatever the answer to this question is, it's still bad programming to write out of bounds.